# publish feed simple facebook fails with "cancelled by user"

Tags: android, facebook, android-simple-facebook

I'm using the [simple facebook library](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook) in my android application. Publishing to the user's timeline works correctly if the user doesn't have the Facebook application installed. However, if the application is installed on the device, the publish action fails with the message: "cancelled by user".

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: If you experience similar behaviour on Simple Facebook Sample -application, contact the library developer, if not, there really needs to be some additional information how you utilise the library.

Comment: Have you followed https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook#usage?

Comment: Yes I even downloaded and ran the sample application, and it works perfectly. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have copied and pasted the code of the onResume and onActivityResult, but nothing seems to work. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, although the onFail method is being called, the post is successfully published through the Facebook app. The error message only shows if the Facebook app is installed in the device. If the app isn't installed the onComplete method is called.

Comment: is there no solution to call onComplete instead of onFail in Publish Listener